# How to change Notification action text color in Android N?

Tags: android

[image: Android N Notification actions]

Is it possible to change the text color of 'FIRE'/'AMBULANCE'/'POLICE'?

Or add icons to them like in older versions of Android?

[image: Pre N Android Notification actions]

Comment: `Notification.Action.Builder` class will help you with your problem with adding icons for action buttons. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.Builder.html
And for changing text color, I am not sure. But I think you can try `Spannable` (I am not sure about this though). 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Comment: Related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290396/set-different-colors-for-notification-actions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178293/notification-coloured-action-button-android-10
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037234/set-background-color-to-notifications-actions-in-android10

Answer (score 15):

To change action text color use:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color=\"" + ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.custom_color) + "\">" + context.getString(R.string.fire) + "</font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

as the action title `CharSequence`, like:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        ...
        .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                            R.drawable.ic_fire,
                            HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color=\"" + ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.custom_color) + "\">" + context.getString(R.string.fire) + "</font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY),
                            actionPendingIntent))
                    .build())
        .build();
```

Comment: Pretty strange that this is the way to do it. On Android 9 it changes the backgroundColor of the button if I set the font color.

Comment: Strange and undocumented I'm afraid, I guessed to use a spannable string judging by its parameter type `CharSequense`.

Comment: Tried it on Android 8 and Android 10 and it behaves as it should

Answer (score 13):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

[`NotificationCompat.Builder.setColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) method is used to set an accent color for the notification, which will also be applied to action buttons' text.

Comment: it will also change the smallIcon color of the notification.

Answer (score 2):

**In kotlin you can add this function for text color change:**

```
private fun getActionText(@StringRes stringRes: Int, @ColorRes colorRes: Int): Spannable? {
            val spannable: Spannable = SpannableString(applicationContext.getText(stringRes))
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
                spannable.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(applicationContext.getColor(colorRes)), 0, spannable.length, 0
                )
            }
            return spannable
        }
```

After that you just call it from `builder`:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_end, getActionText(R.string.reject,R.color.red), rejectPendingIntent)
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_accept, getActionText(R.string.accept,R.color.green), acceptPendingIntent)
```

You can add more button in your notification.

Answer (score 0):

To change the text color of actions and also place an icon to the left of them, use following example.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColorResourceHere))
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Fire", myPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Icons are not shown. I guess they only appear in older android versions.

Comment: addAction button text color changed in android 10.

Answer (score 0):

To add formatting in your text (bold, italic, line breaks, **color** and so on), you can add [styling with HTML markup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML)