# Notification coloured action button Android 10

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0

I'm trying to color the buttons(Action) in Notification like this.
[image]

So far this is what i'm achieved so far.
[image]

Below is the code i'm using

**NotificationService.class**

```
private void showCallNotification(Map<String, String> dataMap) {
        notificationId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceiveCallActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)
                .putExtra(AppConstants.CALL_STATUS, AppConstants.CALL_ACCEPTED)
                .putExtra("title", dataMap.get("title"))
                .putExtra("action", dataMap.get("action"));

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoCallReceiver.class)
                .setAction(AppConstants.INCOMING_CALL_BROADCAST_ACTION)
                .putExtra(AppConstants.CALL_STATUS, AppConstants.CALL_DECLINED)
                .putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action declineAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, getString(R.string.decline_call), cancelPendingIntent);
        NotificationCompat.Action acceptAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, getString(R.string.accept_call), pendingIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, AppConstants.CALL_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(dataMap.get("sender"))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.incoming_call))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTimeoutAfter(CALL_DISMISS_TIME)
                .addAction(declineAction)
                .addAction(acceptAction)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createCallNotificationChannel();
        }

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
```

I'm out of ideas now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073294/how-to-change-notification-action-text-color-in-android-n and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290396/set-different-colors-for-notification-actions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037234/set-background-color-to-notifications-actions-in-android10

Answer (score 18):

Code taken from the Android official [Dialer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/master/java/com/android/incallui/StatusBarNotifier.java#848) app

when you set the action string `getString(R.string.decline_call)` change that with a call to the method

```java
  private Spannable getActionText(@StringRes int stringRes, @ColorRes int colorRes) {
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(context.getText(stringRes));
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
      spannable.setSpan(
          new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getColor(colorRes)), 0, spannable.length(), 0);
    }
    return spannable;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to apply colors for the notification action buttons. Use `spannable` just like Aeron suggested (code from the Dialer app) and the very important thing is to set `USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT` permission. Otherwise colors are ignored in the dark mode or look incorrect in the non dark mode.

Comment: Thanks!! that was the part that I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom layout in your notification. There are `setCustomContentView()` and `setCustomBigContentView` methods:

```
// Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_large);

// Apply the layouts to the notification
Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNE L_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
        .build();
```

Do have a read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)

Comment: After setting `setCustomBigContentView` and `setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())` , notification is not showing up anymore. Anything else i need to be wary of ?

Answer (score -2):

Use custom drawable like this

```
NotificationCompat.Action declineAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_red, getString(R.string.decline_call), cancelPendingIntent);
NotificationCompat.Action acceptAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_green, getString(R.string.accept_call), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: `new NotificationCompat.Action()` is deprecated. Also even with the new method, icon is not showing. And this is not what i'm trying to implement, I'm trying to colour the buttons not add icons to it. Anyways thanks for your quick reply.