# set different colors for notification actions

Tags: java, android, notifications, builder

Hi I am setting a notification for incoming call with two actions : Answer and Decline . I need to set Green color for Answer action and red for Decline . But i couldnt find a solution.

Here is my code :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext,"Call")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_rider_logo)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentTitle(generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("","LBL_SINCH_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT"))
                .setContentText(call.getHeaders().get("Name") +" "+ generalFunc.retrieveLangLBl("","LBL_SINCH_NOTIFICATION_TITLE"));

        builder.addAction(getServiceNotificationAction(mContext, denyCallIntent(mContext,call),R.drawable.ic_call_icon, R.string.decline));
        builder.addAction(getServiceNotificationAction(mContext, answerCallIntent(mContext,call),R.drawable.com_facebook_close, R.string.answer));
 if (callActivityRestricted()) {
        builder.setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL);
    }
 private NotificationCompat.Action getServiceNotificationAction(Context context, Intent intent, int iconResId, int titleResId) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 ? PendingIntent.getForegroundService(context, 0, intent, 0)
                : PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        return new NotificationCompat.Action(iconResId, context.getString(titleResId), pendingIntent);
    }
```

I tried setColor() , but it sets unique color for both actions.

Please help me to solve this . thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try this answer - [Notification Action color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073294/how-to-change-notification-action-text-color-in-android-n/56873390#56873390)

Comment: I tried this method .  it is effective to change the background color not its text color. anyway somehow it fixed my issue . thank you for the reference :)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178293/notification-coloured-action-button-android-10 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037234/set-background-color-to-notifications-actions-in-android10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried your code and achieved it with the help of Spannable class.

```
public void sendOnChannel1(View v) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, activityIntent, 0);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", message);
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColorized(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, getMyActionText(R.string.answer,R.color.green), actionIntent)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, getMyActionText(R.string.decline,R.color.red), actionIntent)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

[image]

Here is a helping method which i used:

```
private Spannable getMyActionText(@StringRes int stringRes, @ColorRes int colorRes) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(this.getText(stringRes));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            spannable.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(this.getColor(colorRes)), 0, spannable.length(), 0);
        }
        return spannable;
    }
```